# How to formaly prove that there exists a $\delta > 0$ that verifies an inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Take $\{ (a_n , b_n) \in \Bbb R^2 |  a_n < b_n \forall\, n \}$.

How do I prove that fixed a $N $ in the naturals and given $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ s.t.

$$(b_1 - a_1 + 2 \delta) (b_2 - a_2 + 2 \delta) \dots (b_N - a_N + 2 \delta) < (b_1 - a_1) \dots (b_N - a_N) + \frac \epsilon 2 $$

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What is $\epsilon$?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Sorry, $\epsilon \in R^+$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\prod_{i=1}^N(b_i-a_i)=P.$ Then $$\prod_{i=1}^N(b_i-a_i+2 d)<P+e/2\iff \prod_{i=1}^N(1+2 d/(b_i-a_i))<1+e/2 P.$$ Let $S=\max_{1\leq i\leq N}1/(b_i-a_i).$  When $1<1+2 d S<(1+e/2 P)^{1/N}$ then the  desired inequality holds.

If $N>1$ then for a given $e>0,$ we cannot have $d$ independently of all $a_1,...,a_N$ and $b_1,...,b_N.$ For example with $N=2,$ for brevity let $c_1=b_1-a_1$ and $c_2=b_2-a_2.$ The desired inequality is then equivalent to $2 d(c_1+c_2)+4 d^2<e/2$.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Not sure if this can help you for $N:=n<\infty$ (I had misunderstood the original question, considering the case for $n\rightarrow \infty$)but

For $$\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{n}$$

$$\prod_{i=1}^n (b_i-a_i+2\delta)=\prod_{i=1}^n \Big(b_i-a_i+2\frac{\epsilon}{n}\Big)$$

As $n\rightarrow \infty$, $$\prod_{i=1}^n \Big(b_i-a_i+2\frac{\epsilon}{n}\Big)\rightarrow \prod_{i=1}^n (b_i-a_i)<\prod_{i=1}^n (b_i-a_i)+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Comment: But $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{n} $ is not the correct delta generally or am I missing something?

Comment: @Monolite What do you mean by generally? (Ah, do you mean for $n<\infty?$)

Comment: Yes. I don't even need the explicit $\delta$ even showing that such a $\delta$ exists would be ok for me, what I meant was I don't think your $\delta$ is ok for a fixed $n$.

Comment: @Monolite It was unclear to me from the original question whether you were looking for a $\delta(N)$ If it's ok with you I will edit the answer to cover only $n\rightarrow \infty$. Hope someone could use it for $N<infty$.